# Как реализовать символьный протокол передачи данных для чтения с помощью ByteBuffer?

Tags: java

Сначала была идея отправить сначала длину строки в байтах а потом разметить буфер нужной длины:

```
ByteBuffer headerByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
ByteBuffer bodyByteBuffer;

socketChannel.read(headerByteBuffer);

headerByteBuffer.flip();

int length = headerByteBuffer.getInt();

bodyByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(length);

socketChannel.read(bodyByteBuffer);

bodyByteBuffer.flip();
```

Ну и далее переводим байты в символы и парсим json.
Но при записи в headerByteBuffer вылезает BufferUnderflowException и как бы не круто

Comment: Так же появилась идея использовать символ разделитель в конце сообщения без передачи его размера. Но тут мне непонятно как заставить CharsetDecoder останавливаться на этом символе или сообщать что нужно ещё дочитать данные

Comment: Так BufferUnderflowException происходит, когда у вас банально не хватает вместимости буффера (записываете больше выделенных вами символов).